# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'singlepropa' with arguments '('mens-shirt-1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls, slug

I am trying to pass 2 parameters from html tag to the urls in django. But I am getting error: NoReverseMatch. If I pass only one parameter then it is working fine but it is generating error whenever i am passing 2 parameters. I have read the documentation for this but I am not clear about that,,and I have also searched for this issues. But nothing is working. Can You please help me to figure it out how I can I fix this?

My href in html tag is:

```
<a href='{% url "update_cart" slug=product.slug qty=10 %}' class="float-right">Add to Cart</a>Add to Cart</a>
```

My urls.py is:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', home.Index.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('signup', signup.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    path('login', login.Login.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('logout', login.logout , name="logout"),
    path('basket', basket.Basket.as_view() , name="basket"),
    path('singlepropa/<str:slug>/<int:qty>', singlepropa.SinglePropa.as_view() , name="singlepropa"),
    path('s/', search.Search.as_view() , name="search"),
    path('update_cart/<str:slug>/<int:qty>', basket.update_cart , name="update_cart"),
]
```

The method for the mapped url is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from MStore.models.cartModel import Cart, CartItem
from MStore.models.productModel import ProductModel
from django.urls import reverse

# login class
class Basket(View):

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            the_id = request.session["cart_id"]
        except:
            the_id = None
        if the_id:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
            context = {'cart': cart}
        else:
            empty_msg = "Your Cart is empty. Please keep shopping!"
            context = {"empty": True, "empty_msg": empty_msg }

        return render(request, 'basket.html', context)


def update_cart(request, slug, qty):
    try:
        the_id = request.session["cart_id"]
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        the_id = new_cart.id
        request.session["cart_id"] = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    try:
        product = ProductModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except ProductModel.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product)
    if created:
        print("Yeah")

    if qty == 0:
        cart_item.delete()
    else:
        cart_item.quantity = qty
        cart_item.save()

    request.session["item_counts"] = cart.cartitem_set.count()

    new_total = 0.00
    for p in cart.cartitem_set.all():
        line_total = float(p.product.price) * p.quantity
        new_total += line_total

    cart.total = round(new_total, 2)
    cart.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("basket"))
```

The error I am getting:

> 

```
    NoReverseMatch at /
>     Reverse for 'singlepropa' with arguments '('mens-shirt-1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['singlepropa/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<qty>[0-9]+)$']
>     Request Method:   GET
>     Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>     Django Version:   3.1.5
>     Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
>     Exception Value:  
>     Reverse for 'singlepropa' with arguments '('mens-shirt-1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['singlepropa/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<qty>[0-9]+)$']
>     Exception Location:   G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py,
> line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
>     Python Executable:    G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>     Python Version:   3.7.3
>     Python Path:  
>     ['G:\\djangoPro\\NShopping',
>      'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
>      'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
>      'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
>      'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
>      'G:\\djangoPro\\EMart\\venv',
>      'G:\\djangoPro\\EMart\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
>     Server time:  Wed, 10 Feb 2021 09:16:40 +0000
```

Full Traceback:

```
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 70, in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 98, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\NShopping\MStore\views\home.py, line 24, in get
        return render(request, 'index.html', data) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py, line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py, line 61, in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 170, in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py, line 150, in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py, line 211, in render
                    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context)) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py, line 446, in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py, line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) …
▶ Local vars
G:\djangoPro\EMart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update_cart** has only 1 parameter product slug. and the issue is in **singlepropa** URL.

```
<a href='{% url "update_cart" product.slug %}' class="float-right">Add to Cart</a>
<a href='{% url "singlepropa" product.slug 10 %}' class="float-right">Add to Cart</a>
```

this will fix your issue.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Thank you @c.grey for the response but I have read the documentation and I need to pass two parameters in singlepropa as defined in my function update_cart(request, slug, qty). I have updated update_cart with 2 parameters and I have tried the format in the doc but it is still not working.

Comment: @NahidAkhtar where is your **SinglePropa** function.

Comment: Thank You @c.grey for the great help. Got this. I was not supposed to pass it to my SinglePropa function. The problem is solved.